# if $f$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ and differentiable at $(a,b)-\{c\}$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=A$ then $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c)=A$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I'm having some issues with this proof. What I have so far is this: \

Let's divide the interval $(a,b)-\{c\}$ in $(a,c)\cup(c,b)$.
Because we know that the $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=A$ that means that, given $\epsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)-A|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$.
We choose $x,y\in(c-\delta,c)$ such that $x<y$ and we consider the interval $[x,y]$. We know $f$ is differentiable in $(x,y)$ and by the MVT we can find a $z\in(x,y)$ such that:$$f'(z)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$
and because $x,y\in(c-\delta,c)$ that means $|f'(z)-A|<\epsilon$.
Let's do the same thing for the interval $(c,c+\delta)$ and find a $\bar{z}\in(c,c+\delta)$ such that $|f(\bar{z})-A|<\epsilon$.\

Here is where I'm stuck. And I'm also not sure it that approach is the correct one.

Comment: Is there an unstated hypothesis that $f$ is (defined and) continuous at $c$? If not, consider the function defined by letting $a=-1$, $b=1$, $c=0$, and $f(x)=0$  for $x<0$, $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$, and $f(0)=73$.

Comment: It is actually continuous at $c$. In fact it is continuous at (a,b). Continuity is not stated in my notes, that's why I overlooked it, but it is part of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, continuity at $c$ is an essential requirement. Otherwise, you can make $f$ discontinuous at $c$, which would imply $f$ is not differentiable at $c$.
$$
f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$
Since $f$ is continuous at $c$, $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-f(c))=\lim_{x\to c}(x-c)=0$, and you can apply L'Hospital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=A
$$

Comment: I think I understand but let me make sure. What you did, basically was to define $g(x)=f(x)-f(c)$ and $h(x)=x-c$. That way you'd have $g'(x)=f'(x)$ and $h'(x)=1$ and the $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{g'(x)}{h'(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$. Is that it?

Comment: @TheMadMaxIV Yes. Note that L'Hospital's rule doesn't require $g'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ to exist at $x=c$. They have to exist in a neighborhood of $c$ but not necessarily at $c$. You can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) about the rule.